# Why dayClick event of JQuery FullCalendar is not firing everytime?

Tags: jquery, date, fullcalendar

I am using [JQuery fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). I have implemented [dayClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) event as shown below:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
alert('Day clicked ' + date);
 }
});
```

The code works fine, but for not for every date. It fires click event for few date box but not for every date box.

How I can trace this issue.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111686/fullcalendar-dayclick-callback-not-firing) it is specified that click event is not firing, but in my case its firing sometime.

Comment: I just grabbed a copy of fullcalendar and dayclick works for me!

Comment: I hope on every date it is working?

Comment: It is! Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j_mmontero/of5x5egr/7/